# why is add_options_page() not working?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I am trying to add something simple, just an admin_option_page(). After I have activated my plugin it does not seem to be working.... I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
class Settings{

    public function __construct()
    {

        add_action("admin_menu",[$this,"myPluginMenu"]);


    }



    public function myPluginMenu(){

        add_options_page("My plugin menu","Plugin menu","manage-options","my-plugin-menu",[$this,"pluginHtml"]);

    }


    public function pluginHtml(){

        if(!current_user_can("manage_options")){
            wp_die(__("Sorry you cant access this page"));
        }


        echo "<div class='wrap'>";
        echo "<p>Here is where the form would go if it had options</p>";
        echo "</div>";

    }


}

new Settings();
```

Comment: Please note that questions asking for debugging help must include description of the current "incorrect" result. Are you getting an error, or simply nothing happens? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Alex See the user's answer - it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

I found out what i went wrong

the string "manage-options" was supposed to be "manage_options"